# Pickling cv2.KeyPoint causes PicklingError

Tags: python, opencv

I want to search surfs in all images in a given directory and save their keypoints and descriptors for future use. I decided to use pickle as shown below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import pickle
import cv2

class Frame:
  def __init__(self, filename):
    surf = cv2.SURF(500, 4, 2, True)
    self.filename = filename
    self.keypoints, self.descriptors = surf.detect(cv2.imread(filename, cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE), None, False)

if __name__ == '__main__':

  Fdb = open('db.dat', 'wb')
  base_path = "img/"
  frame_base = []

  for filename in os.listdir(base_path):
    frame_base.append(Frame(base_path+filename))
    print filename

  pickle.dump(frame_base,Fdb,-1)

  Fdb.close()
```

When I try to execute, I get a following error:

```
File "src/pickle_test.py", line 23, in <module>
    pickle.dump(frame_base,Fdb,-1)
...
pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'cv2.KeyPoint'>: it's not the same object as cv2.KeyPoint
```

Does anybody know, what does it mean and how to fix it? I am using Python 2.6 and Opencv 2.3.1

Thank you a lot

Comment: Answer heavily link to this post's answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50337569/pickle-exception-for-cv2-boost-when-using-multiprocessing/50394788#50394788

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot dump cv2.KeyPoint to a pickle file.  I had the same issue, and managed to work around it by essentially serializing and deserializing the keypoints myself before dumping them with Pickle.

So represent every keypoint and its descriptor with a tuple:

```
temp = (point.pt, point.size, point.angle, point.response, point.octave, 
        point.class_id, desc)
```

Append all these points to some list that you then dump with Pickle.

Then when you want to retrieve the data again, load all the data with Pickle:

```
temp_feature = cv2.KeyPoint(x=point[0][0],y=point[0][1],_size=point[1], _angle=point[2], 
                            _response=point[3], _octave=point[4], _class_id=point[5]) 
temp_descriptor = point[6]
```

Create a cv2.KeyPoint from this data using the above code, and you can then use these points to construct a list of features.

I suspect there is a neater way to do this, but the above works fine (and fast) for me.  You might have to play around with your data format a bit, as my features are stored in format-specific lists.  I tried to present the above using my idea at its generic base.  I hope that this may help you.

Answer (score 24):

Part of the issue is `cv2.KeyPoint` is a function in python that returns a `cv2.KeyPoint` object. Pickle is getting confused because, literally, "`<type 'cv2.KeyPoint'>` [is] `not the same object as cv2.KeyPoint`". That is, `cv2.KeyPoint` is a function object, while the type was `cv2.KeyPoint`. Why OpenCV is like that, I can only make guesses at unless I go digging. I have a feeling it has something to do with it being a wrapper around a C/C++ library.

Python does give you the ability to fix this yourself. [I found the inspiration on this post about pickling methods of classes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38509409/786020).

I actually use this clip of code, highly modified from the original in the post

```
import copyreg
import cv2

def _pickle_keypoints(point):
    return cv2.KeyPoint, (*point.pt, point.size, point.angle,
                          point.response, point.octave, point.class_id)

copyreg.pickle(cv2.KeyPoint().__class__, _pickle_keypoints)
```

Key points of note:

- In Python 2, you need to use `copy_reg` instead of `copyreg` and `point.pt[0], point.pt[1]` instead of `*point.pt`.
- You can't directly access the `cv2.KeyPoint` class for some reason, so you make a temporary object and use that.
- The `copyreg` patching will use the otherwise problematic `cv2.KeyPoint` function as I have specified in the output of `_pickle_keypoints` when unpickling, so we don't need to implement an unpickling routine.
- And to be nauseatingly complete, `cv2::KeyPoint::KeyPoint` is an overloaded function in C++, but in Python, this isn't exactly a thing. Whereas in the C++, there's a function that takes the point for the first argument, in Python, it would try to interpret that as an `int` instead. The `*` unrolls the point into two arguments, `x` and `y` to match the only `int` argument constructor.

I had been using [casper's excellent solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11985056/786020) until I realized this was possible.

Comment: Shouldn't ``*point.pt`` be ``point.pt``? Also, I am getting a ``TypeError: a float is required`` in the ``load_reduce`` function of pickle. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: @sha1 It should be `*point.pt` to seperate it into x and y. The constructor of `cv2.Keypoint` requires that, hence the TypeError you encounter. Alternatively, use `point.pt[0], point.pt[1]` at the cost of a small amount of speed per point, and to be able to use it in legacy code that still requires python 2.

Comment: This is the best answer. Literally nailed it!

Answer (score 1):

A similar solution to the one provided by Poik. Just call this once before pickling.

```
def patch_Keypoint_pickiling(self):
    # Create the bundling between class and arguments to save for Keypoint class
    # See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50337569/pickle-exception-for-cv2-boost-when-using-multiprocessing/50394788#50394788
    def _pickle_keypoint(keypoint): #  : cv2.KeyPoint
        return cv2.KeyPoint, (
            keypoint.pt[0],
            keypoint.pt[1],
            keypoint.size,
            keypoint.angle,
            keypoint.response,
            keypoint.octave,
            keypoint.class_id,
        )
    # C++ Constructor, notice order of arguments : 
    # KeyPoint (float x, float y, float _size, float _angle=-1, float _response=0, int _octave=0, int _class_id=-1)

    # Apply the bundling to pickle
    copyreg.pickle(cv2.KeyPoint().__class__, _pickle_keypoint)
```

More than for the code, this is for the incredibly clear explanation available there : https://stackoverflow.com/a/50394788/11094914

Please note that if you want to expand this idea to other "unpickable" class of openCV, you only need to build a similar function to "_pickle_keypoint". Be sure that you store attributes in the same order as the constructor. You can consider copying the C++ constructor, even in Python, as I did. Mostly C++ and Python constructors seems not to differ too much.

I has issue with the "pt" tuple. However, a C++ constructor exists for X and Y separated coordinates, and thus, allow this fix/workaround.

Answer (score 0):

In my implementation I was storing Keypoints in a class of mine, and that was preventing the entire class from pickling correctly. Expanding on @hjweide answer, destructuring and restructuring the keypoints like so worked well for me:

```
class FeatureMeasurement:
    def __init__(self, points, keypoints, descriptors, image=None, Q=None):
       
       ...

       # Destructure the keypoints object and store the data in a list so we can pickle it
       self._keypoints = [[p.pt, p.size, p.angle, p.response, p.octave, p.class_id] for p in keypoints]


   @property
   def keypoints(self):
       return [cv2.KeyPoint(x[0][0], x[0][1], x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5]) for x in self._keypoints]
```

This allowed me to pickle just fine while keeping my interface the same.