# OpenCV-Python : Find a code for writing keypoins to a file

Tags: python, opencv

I am using OpenCV-Python binding to write my image processing application. I am finding a way to write keypoints of a image in to a file which we can get back for matching purpose. There is code in C/C++ to do this, but could not find a way to this by using python

Please anyone have an idea about this, please share with me & all of us

Thanks

Comment: This might be helpful, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045363/pickling-cv2-keypoint-causes-picklingerror

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is how you can do it, inspired from the link I gave earlier.

**Save keypoints in a file**

```
import cv2
import cPickle

im=cv2.imread("/home/bikz05/Desktop/dataset/checkered-3.jpg")
gr=cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
d=cv2.FeatureDetector_create("SIFT")
kp=d.detect(gr)

index = []
for point in kp:
    temp = (point.pt, point.size, point.angle, point.response, point.octave, 
        point.class_id) 
    index.append(temp)

# Dump the keypoints
f = open("/home/bikz05/Desktop/dataset/keypoints.txt", "w")
f.write(cPickle.dumps(index))
f.close()
```

**Load and Display keypoints in the image**

```
import cv2
import cPickle

im=cv2.imread("/home/bikz05/Desktop/dataset/checkered-3.jpg")

index = cPickle.loads(open("/home/bikz05/Desktop/dataset/keypoints.txt").read())

kp = []

for point in index:
    temp = cv2.KeyPoint(x=point[0][0],y=point[0][1],_size=point[1], _angle=point[2], 
                            _response=point[3], _octave=point[4], _class_id=point[5]) 
    kp.append(temp)

# Draw the keypoints
imm=cv2.drawKeypoints(im, kp);
cv2.imshow("Image", imm);
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

**INPUT IMAGE to 1st script**

[image]

**Displayed IMAGE in 2nd script**

[image]

Comment: I tried the code, the descriptors are on the same image in both the images. Check the code, I have dumped `pt` also.

Comment: I'l try it and let you know. Thanks

Comment: Works flawlessly on my system.

Comment: Did you compare the output which is drawn with dump key points with the output which is drawn the key point in the normal process ?

Comment: Yes, they are on the same pixel locations, are you modifying this code? Are you drawing the keypoints on the same image? Are their sizes same? Share your code, it will be helpful.

Comment: Finally i had found the issue. It is a mistake of my code .Now it is working correctly. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have find a way to do it without "pickle".

```
  import cv2

  img1 = cv2.imread("bat1.jpg")
  gr_img1 = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
  sift = cv2.SIFT()
  kps = sift.detect(gr_img1)
  f = open("bat_dump.txt", "w")

  for point in kps:
    p = str(point.pt[0]) + "," + str(point.pt[1]) + "," + str(point.size) + "," + str(point.angle) + "," + str(
    point.response) + "," + str(point.octave) + "," + str(point.class_id) + "\n"
    f.write(p)

  f.close()

  kps = []
  lines = [line.strip() for line in open('bat_dump.txt')]

  for line in lines:
    list = line.split(',')
    kp = cv2.KeyPoint(x=float(list[0]), y=float(list[1]), _size=float(list[2]), _angle=float(list[3]),
                  _response=float(list[4]), _octave=int(list[5]), _class_id=int(list[6]))
    kps.append(kp)

  img2 = cv2.imread("bat1.jpg") 
  img2 = cv2.drawKeypoints(img2, kps)
  cv2.imshow("img2", img2)
  cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score -1):

For this i would suggest using Pickle or cPickle. Its simple and for me it works in the most situations. A short introduction you can find on [PyMOTW - Pickle](http://pymotw.com/2/pickle/).

To note is that you can `dump` more times in a File and able to get your data back with `loads` for each `dump`.

Edit: If you wish to save the data into a file, here is a short snippet:

```
import pickle

data = ['your stuff']

with open('fileNameToSave.ext', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(data, f, -1)  # -1 for best compression available
```

If you need more control at how the data is stored, you could use [Struct (PyMOTW)](http://pymotw.com/2/struct/).
Here you have full control but also have to compress the data yourself if memory matter. In return you have control over Endianness (Byte-Order), Padding etc. So cross-language data-exchange is relative simple.

Hope i could help :)

Comment: But this answer does't tell how to save the cv2's KeyPoint data type. For me `pickle.dump(keypoints, open('myKeypoints.ext', 'wb'), -1)` raises the error: TypeError: can't pickle cv2.KeyPoint objects.