# Can't import custom python module using multiprocess library

Tags: python-2.7, pickle, python-multiprocessing

Just getting started with using the `multiprocessing` library in my code base to parallelise a simple for loop, where previously, in a serial for loop, I would import a custom configuration `.py` file and pass it to be a function to be run.

However I'm having issues with passing in the configuration module to be parellelised.

NB. There are multiple custom `configuration.py` which I want to pass into the different processes.

Example:

```
def get_custom_config(): 
   config_list = []
   for project_config in configs:
       config = importlib.import_module("config.%s.%s" % (prefix, project_config)
       config_list.append(config)
   return config_list

def print_config(config):
   print config.something_in_config_file

if __name__ = "__main__":
   config_list = get_custom_config()

   pool = mp.Pool(processes=2)
   pool.map(print_config, config_list)
```

Returns:

```
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 251, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 567, in get
    raise self._value
cPickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'module'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.module failed
```

What is the best way of passing a module to a parallel process?

Comment: You want to use python2.7 only or Python 3 is also ok? If so try this with Python 3 as well

Comment: @TarunLalwani I would like to use python2.7 only if possible!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do have a possible solution for you, but I don't like the approach you have.

```
config = importlib.import_module("config.%s.%s" % (prefix, project_config)
```

You should try and have config as a dictionary of key value pairs instead as a module. Or import it that way.

The issue is that `functions` and `modules` are not picklable by default in Python 2.7. Functions are picklable by default in Python 3.X and modules are still not.

```
import importlib
import multiprocessing as mp

configs = ["abc", "def"]
import copy_reg
import types


def _pickle_module(module):
    module_name = module.__name__
    print("pickling" + module_name)
    path = getattr(module, "__file__", None)
    return _unpickle_module, (module_name, path)


def _unpickle_module(module_name, path):
    return importlib.import_module(module_name)

copy_reg.pickle(types.ModuleType, _pickle_module, _unpickle_module)


def get_custom_config():
    config_list = []
    for project_config in configs:
        config = importlib.import_module("config.%s" % (project_config))
        config_list.append(config)
    return config_list


def print_config(config):
    print (vars(config))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    config_list = get_custom_config()

    pool = mp.Pool(processes=2)
    pool.map(print_config, config_list)
```

This basically re-imports the module in the other process, so do remember you are not sharing data between them. This is a good read only variables.

But as I mentioned passing modules to a different process makes less sense. Try to fix your approach instead of using the code I posted

PS: Solution inspired from [Can't pickle <type 'cv2.BRISK'>: attribute lookup cv2.BRISK failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38150402/cant-pickle-type-cv2-brisk-attribute-lookup-cv2-brisk-failed)

Comment: If I'm using the module as read-only, would using this method be okay? Or is this just bad practice, and instead I should do what you suggested and import the module into a dictionary instead as better practice? (Thanks for the working code as well!)

Comment: You can import configs at run-time, no issues with that. But when you are sending `config_list` to the pool, it should not contain modules, either send actual configs or pass just the module names and let each process load its own copy of the config