# Python OpenCV dump a cv2 object to file?

Tags: python, opencv, pickle

How to dump a cv2 object (more preciely a list or a np.array containing these objects), for example keypoints (type: `cv2.KeyPoint`) or matches (type: `cv2.DMatch`), to a file on disk in order to import them later rather than re-runing a time consumming (several hours up to days on a low end computer) algorithm on a lot of images (> 50'000)?

It doesn't work with (c)Pickle.
Typical errors are:

```
PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'cv2.KeyPoint'>: it's not the same object as cv2.KeyPoint
```

or

```
PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'cv2.DMatch'>: it's not the same object as cv2.DMatch
```

And I can not find any `dump` or saving/export method on cv2.

The script runs using Python 2.7 on both Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 7.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pickle error cv2.Boost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50337569/pickle-error-cv2-boost) (has an answer, but was asked after this question, and is not KeyPoint-specific - but nor is the title of this question)

Answer (score 0):

If you are insistent on saving Keypoints in a text/pickle file, then you must convert the Keypoint object so that it is pickle-able.

Use the SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11985056/6411572) to break up the object into a pickle-able format and to load it back to your code.

Comment: This is a good answer in the KeyPoints case - what about others? Must every class be serialized in a bespoke fashion?

Comment: I believe so. There might be cases that I haven't used that are already serialized.